# I can't get my animation to work on load of my website using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So the problem I am having is that I can't seem to get my jQuery Function to add a class to start my animation? I have tried a lot of different ways to get it to work, none of them are working!

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onload = function render(){
    $('.title .sub-title').addClass('render');
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
.render {
    animation-name: render;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes render {
    0% { transform: translateX(-800px); }
    100% { transform: translateX( 0px ); }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-header-title-wrapper">
    <h1 class="title">Template 1</h1><!--Need To add animation 
    <h4 class="sub-title">- Here is a Template Slogan -</h4><!--Need To add animation to-->
</div>
```

Please can someone help?

It would be very beneficial!

Comment: `.sub-title` element appears commented? `window.onload` is not necessary

Comment: Please just checkout the jQuery selector and html structure.

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah I added in the comments In this question, its not like that in my actual code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.title, .sub-title').addClass('render');
});
```

The code in your example is targeting a `.sub-title` element nested within a `.title` element. Including a comma in your CSS selector should fix this.

Comment: oh thank you, It is always the simple things I miss.

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score -1):

Your `.sub-title` class is commented out. Try this:

```
<div class="site-header-title-wrapper">
    <h1 class="title">Template 1</h1>
    <h4 class="sub-title">- Here is a Template Slogan -</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the comment for "Need to add animation here" in this question but its not like that in my actual code, but thanks anyway!